# Kusto: Handling null parameter in user defined funtion

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am writing a custom User defined function in kusto where I want to have some optional parameters to the function which will be used in the "where" clause. I want to dynamically handle this. For example: If the value is present, then my where clause should consider that column filter, else it should not be included in the "where" clause>

Eg (psuedo code where value is not null):

```
function Calculate(string:test)
{
  T | where test == test | order by timestamp 
}
```

Eg (psuedo code where value is null or empty. My final query should look like this):

```
function Calculate(string:test)
{
  T | order by timestamp 
}
```

What is the efficient way to implement this. I will call this function from my c# class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a function with a [default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#default-values) for its argument, and use the logical `or` operator and the [`isempty()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/isemptyfunction) to implement the condition you've described.

for example:

(*note: the following is demonstrated using a [`let` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/letstatement), but can be applied similarly to [stored functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/functions)*)

```
let T = range x from 1 to 5 step 1 | project x = tostring(x)
;
let F = (_x: string = "") {
    T
    | where isempty(_x) or _x == x
    | order by x desc
}
;
F("abc")
```

- if you run `F()` or `F("")` (i.e. no argument, or an empty string as the argument) - it will return all values 1-5.
- if you run `F("3")` - it will return a single record with the value `3`.
- if you run `F("abc")` - it will return no records.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to get going and was able to complete my additional logics

Comment: Can you let me know how to do the same for string array or int array? My parameter for a function looks like f(names:dynamic) and am expecting the parameter to be ["A","B",C"]

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73070192/7861807