# Passing Array parameter to Kusto user defined function and doing null check

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to have optional parameter (string array). So, My parameter for a function looks like f(names:dynamic=dynamic([])) to set default if i am not passing this parameter. However below check doen't work. Any pointers on how to do null check and if present apply that filter else retrieve all values.

```
| where isempty(_x) or x in(_x)
```

Comment: Make sure that you close the loop by approving one of the answers that you got.

Answer (score 1):

you could try using `set_has_element()`.

for example:

```
let T = range x from 1 to 5 step 1
;
let F = (_x: dynamic = dynamic(null)) {
    T
    | where isnull(_x) or set_has_element(_x, x)
    | order by x desc
}
;
F(dynamic([1,2,4]))
```

| x |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 2 |
| 1 |

Though, please note the following, regarding stored functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#features-that-are-currently-unsupported-by-user-defined-functions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

##### 1.

`x in (_x)` is a valid syntax

---

```
let _x = dynamic([1,2,4]);
print   is_2_in_x = 2 in (_x)
       ,is_3_in_x = 3 in (_x)
```

| is_2_in_x | is_3_in_x |
| --- | --- |
| true | false |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVGIr1CwVUipzEvMzUzWiDbUMdIxidW05uUqKMrMK1FQUMgsjjeKz8wDKzNSyMxT0Iiv0OTlUoAAHaC0MUzaGCYNAMPOrGJYAAAA)

##### 2.

Figuring out if array is null/empty is complicated and the use of `isnull()` and/or `isempty()` is not sufficient for the task.
Please note the 3 last options in the demo below for potential solutions.

```
let F = (_x_as_str:string = "", _x: dynamic = dynamic(null)) 
{
    print   _x_as_str               = _x_as_str
           ,isnull                  = isnull(_x)
           ,isempty                 = isempty(_x)
           ,array_length            = array_length(_x)
           ,is_1st_null             = isnull(_x[0])
           ,is_1st_empty            = isempty(_x[0])
           ,coalesce_array_length   = coalesce(array_length(_x), 0)
}
;
union   F("dynamic([1,2,4])",dynamic([1,2,4]))
       ,F()
       ,F("dynamic(null)", dynamic(null))
       ,F("dynamic([])" , dynamic([]))
```

| _x_as_str | isnull | isempty | array_length | is_1st_null | is_1st_empty | coalesce_array_length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dynamic([1,2,4]) | false | false | 3 | false | false | 3 |
|  | true | true |  | true | true | 0 |
| dynamic([]) | false | false | 0 | true | true | 0 |
| dynamic(null) | true | true |  | true | true | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA21RywqDMBC8C/7DklMCOdjSk8WrPyESgg1WiLGYCErpv3f71CQOhCQ7O7sDo5WDEgqgYhbSCuvGHE9nWqwRwkHMOVwWI/uuwcr3Rc2kNWOQJvc0AcQNFQ7v/xDwUazMR/AF7+xrFEQo4MOgLRYqVH9zy67izcQSOY5yEVqZ1l19yZbZWyUO1onI4cZcldX7osjk1l+sagaplW2UCLwW8GNo6JVDhkMeaXJOk8l0g8H2kpJfRNWBH/mpZoSHlXU1L6n3IV6+mL6f925rhStg7cQvewL/goPhVAIAAA==)