# How to print all rows if no parameter is passed in Kusto Function

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a requirement to print all rows if parameter is null is passed and if not null, use it in where clause

I am writing a Kusto function where I want to have some fixed parameters to the function which will be used in the "where" clause. I want to dynamically handle this. For example: If the value is present, then my where clause should consider that column filter, else it should not be included in the "where" clause>

I saw this question which seems to be doing it but unbale to fit in my requirement to the pseudo code in the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72959606/kusto-handling-null-parameter-in-user-defined-funtion) post.

My Table Name: **SecurityGroups**
My where clause operator is **GroupType**
My Current Sample Kusto Function:

```html
.create-or-alter function fnGetSecurityGroups(groupType:string) {
SecurityGroups | where GroupType =~ groupType
}
```

Comment: Something like `where GroupType =~ groupType or groupType == ""`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same query by @[Yoni L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7861807/yoni-l) in the post which you have provided will work for you.

As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/null-values?pivots=azuredataexplorer#null-literals),

> null values are not supported for string data type.

So, use the empty string(`""`) as the default value for the string parameter in your function.

As you want to print the rows, after the `where` clause, don't add anything.

**My sample:**

```
let r = datatable(name:string, game:string)
[   
    "Rakesh","TT",
    "Laddu","BB",
    "Virat","Cricket"
];

let F1 = (_name: string = "") {
    r
    | where isempty(_name) or name == _name
};

F1("Rakesh");
```

Here, as we are using `or` operator,

- first it will check whether the given value is empty string or not. If it is empty string(`True`), then it won't check the next condition in where and it will directly print all the rows.
- If it is not empty string, then it will check the where column condition and prints the rows as per the condition.

**My output when no value provided:**

[image]

**When value provided:**

[image]